# Python 3.8-alpine docker compose failing

Tags: django, docker, python-3.8

I have been running an app without docker and have just added in `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose`.

The issue I am having is that after I successfuly build the app, `runserver` produces the below error when I run either that or `migrate`.

```
➜  app git:(master) sudo docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py runserver"
Error loading shared library libpython3.8.so.1.0: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/python)
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/python: Py_BytesMain: symbol not found
failed to resize tty, using default size
                                        %                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
➜  app git:(master) sudo docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py migrate"  
Error loading shared library libpython3.8.so.1.0: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/python)
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/python: Py_BytesMain: symbol not found
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
MAINTAINER realize-sec

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ""
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

What am I doing wrong that is causing this?

When I run without docker using `python3 manage.py runserver` it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I haven’t tested the build, I don’t know whether any of these things will help you to ultimately build your containers, however here are some observations to hopefully set you on the right path.

- Your context is a null string and is usually a dot (.)
- You typically finish the Dockerfile with the following command:

`CMD [ "python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]`

So you can remove that from your compose file.

Other than that, on a more general note, although Alpine images are small, they are prone to breaking because of the additional dependencies and packages that you need to add/remove. You’re probably better off with going for the slim version overall. The original build will take a bit longer but it will be more manageable.

Also, if you’re running a modern version of Docker on your machine, then you can move the syntax version of the compose file to version 3.7 or 3.8, depending upon your version of Docker.

Comment: Thanks, Wayne. What image is a better option?

Comment: You could choose either `slim` or `buster` for your base image.